# Error using Tikz and Tikz-qtree with Acrobat Distiller

Tags: tikz-pgf, errors, tikz-qtree, ps2pdf

My tag follows:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{linguex}%
\usepackage{tikz}%
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.text,calc,arrows.meta}%
\usepackage{tikz-qtree}%
\usepackage{adjustbox}%%
\usepackage{stmaryrd}%
\let\llbrack\llbracket%
\let\rrbrack\rrbracket%

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\ex.
\Tree [.CauseP [.DP \edge[roof]; {`the zog'} ] [ [.\textsc{cause} ] [
[.\textsc{past} ] [.vP \edge[roof]; {`dissolved the
house'} ]]] ]

\end{document}
```

Code works fine and output generated cleanly. For generating PDF file, I am using the command `dvips -Ppdf -t a4 test.dvi` and then using `Acrobat Distiller` to convert PS to PDF format, and that is my requirement. Using `PDFLaTeX` and `PS2PDF` are not advisable. While converting PS to PDF, following error occurred:

```
%%[ Error: limitcheck; OffendingCommand: save ]%%

Stack:
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-
-save-


%%[ Flushing: rest of job (to end-of-file) will be ignored ]%%
%%[ Warning: PostScript error. No PDF file produced. ] %%
```

How can I fix this? Please suggest...

Also, please confirm using `Tikz` and its supporting files may cause this error?

Comment: Does it produce a proper PDF with PDFLaTeX? Then it is your conversion that has an issue

Comment: @percusse I agreed that some special problem happened while converting PS to PDF by using Adobe Distiller, is there any advise to overcome the issue that I am suffering....

Comment: Why is it not advisable to use a method which works, rather than one which doesn't? Have you tried converting using other tools?

Comment: I'm having the same problems using  TL2019 with `dvilualatex`. I have a limitation to use dvi mode so this error is annoying.